# Turning a quantile calculation output into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantile

I am trying to calculate quantile output and am close, but not sure how to turn my output into a data frame.

```
x.groupby(['day'])['mins'].quantile(.5)
```

This gives me what I want,

The output isn't a data frame and I needed the output to be a data frame.

Output looks like:

```
    day
    2019-06-28    3.0
    2019-06-30    4.0
    2019-07-02    3.0
    2019-07-06    3.0
    2019-07-08    3.0
    Name: mins, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to do reset_index()

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mins': [1, 2, 2, 10, 6],
                   'day':['2019-06-28','2019-06-28','2019-06-30','2019-06-30','2019-07-02']})

res = df.groupby(['day'])['mins'].quantile(0.5).reset_index()
res.rename(columns={'mins':'quantile_value'},inplace=True)
print(res)
```

```
          day  quantile_value
0  2019-06-28   1.5
1  2019-06-30   6.0
2  2019-07-02   6.0
```

I hope it would solve your problem